# Add an element before text with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I have some XML where I want to insert a new element before the text.

I tried:

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = "<root><foo>some text</foo></root>"
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
root.find("foo")
foo.insert(0, etree.Element("bar"))
etree.tostring(foo)
```

and the result was

```xml
<foo>some text<bar/></foo>
```

when I was hoping for

```xml
<foo><bar/>some text</foo>
```

Bearing in mind that the `foo` element may actually be quite complicated.

The best I could come with was

```py
def insert_before(elem, child):
    elem.insert(0, child)
    child.tail, elem.text = elem.text, None
```

But is there a function or argument in the API that I missed?

Comment: I think you're doing it right. You have to set the tail to get text after a tag

Answer (score 0):

Question is pretty old, but for those struggling with this.

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html import builder as E

# example 1
label = E.LABEL('my label')
bar = etree.Element('bar')
label.insert(0, bar)
bar.tail = label.text
label.text = None
print(etree.tostring(label, encoding="unicode"))
# output => <label><bar/>my label</label>


# example 2
bar = etree.Element('bar')
bar.tail = 'my label'
label = E.LABEL(bar)
print(etree.tostring(label, encoding="unicode"))
# output => <label><bar/>my label</label>
```